# MongoDB aggregate $lookup returning empty array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have two collections that I would like to aggregate using $lookup.

Here's a document from 1 collection, col_1:
Area:

```
 {'_id': ObjectId('6476fa4d10cbd495135ea9d5'),
'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 16, 0, 0),
'lat': 50.636,
'long': 170.33,}`
```

Here's a document from another collection, col_2:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('6476fa4910cbd495135ea9c0'),
 'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 16, 0, 0),
 'station': 75002,}
```

I am trying to join them based on the "date", I know that there are several rows in col_1 that matches to a row in col_2 based on the dates, hence my code:

```
results = col_2.aggregate([
    {"$lookup":
        {
            "from": "col_1",
            "localField": "date",
            "foreignField": "date",
            "as": "aggregated"
        }}
])

for document in ans:
    pprint(document)
```

it returns an empty `aggregated` array.

I've tried matching each document to check that common dates between the two exists, and using $match and $unwind. The `aggregated` array always returns empty:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('6476fa4910cbd495135ea9c0'),
 'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 16, 0, 0),
 'station': 75002,},
 'aggregated': []}
```

Not sure what's wrong here, would love some inputs.

Comment: Does the same thing happen using `for document in results:`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yeah, it still returns an empty array. When I query with find("date" : datetime(____), it works, but just when I use $lookup it doesn't

Comment: The collections are in the same database, yes? If yes, somehow the dates stored in the collections are different.  If you `"$lookup"` and only compare the `"day"` like shown as part of this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SZ5RVqkGIz8), are there any matches?

Comment: @rickhg12hs thanks for the help, I tried running it, and it returns nothing, which I assume is because the join is empty.

Comment: By _"nothing"_, do you mean that `"aggregated"` is an empty array?

Comment: Are the collections in the **same** database?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yup, the aggregated array is empty, and both collections are in the same database. I've fix this issue, which was because the "from". I loaded the collection into a variable of different name (I'm using pymongo), changing the from into the original collection's name makes it work. Thanks for your help so far, really appreciate it

Comment: Glad you're making progress.  Note that if you ask for help with a coding problem, you should show the actual code you are using.  ;-)